# opengl glrotatef won't rotate properly

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rotation

Suppose I had a drawing at point `(50,60,20)` and I wanted to rotate this in each side of a table. 
Base of the drawing below, I want to rotate the green circle to the right side, back side, and left side. My implementation was 
 `glRotatef(plate_rotate, 50, 0, 0);` since this would be in the middle to the table, with a vertex x = 50. however this does not work.

```
glRotatef(90, 50, 0, 0); would not work. 


Table dimension 
int xL = 25;
int xR = 75;

int yT = 60;
int yB = 55;

int zF = 25;
int zB = -25;



static float tableTop[8][3] =
{
    { xL, yT, zF },
    { xR, yT, zF },
    { xR, yT, zB },
    { xL, yT, zB },
    //bottom
    { xL, yB, zF },
    { xR, yB, zF },
    { xR, yB, zB },
    { xL, yB, zB },

};
```

[image]

Comment: What is `centerglRotate()`? That's not an OpenGL function. Did you mean just `glRotate()`?

Comment: Please give more details in your question: as is, it is impossible to answer. In particular, give your code for `centerglRotatef`, and a complete scenario that uses it.

Comment: I apologize, I meant glRotatef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to translate your object to the origin, rather than doing what you're doing... the x,y,z coordinates in `glRotatef` are a direction vector not a spatial coordinate. There is no difference between `glRotatef (90, 1, 0, 0)` and `glRotatef (90, 50, 0, 0)` because both vectors are identical when normalized.

#### Consider this instead (pay attention to the order in which these things happen):

```
glTranslatef ( 50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);               // 3. Move back
glRotatef    (plate_rotate, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   // 2. Rotate around X-axis
glTranslatef (-50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);               // 1. Move X=50 to origin
```